# Nodelet unloading based on misconfiguration in onInit()

Tags: nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently trying to determine if anyone has come up with a sound way of unloading a nodelet based on error conditions in either the onInit() function, or in normal operation of the node.

Essentially, I would like to sanity check all of the nodelet's parameters in the onInit() function, and then stop operation if the parameters don't fall within the correct bounds.

Obviously, I could probably return before loading all of the publishers and subscribers, but this leaves the nodelet loaded, which I don't feel is a terribly clean solution.

Has anyone else come up with a better mechanism for this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46686/nodelet-unloading-based-on-misconfiguration-in-oninit()/) by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6414 on 2012-10-24

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like the current best solution is still calling the manager's 'unloadNodelet' service.  You'll have to use a parameter (or some REALLY clever namespace/nodehandle tricks) to determine what service to call.

Here's a relevant mailing list thread:
http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/nodelet-shutdown-unload-itself-requestShutdown-td3151148.html

Here's the still open ticket:
https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4431

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2012-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2012-10-24**:
Has that ticket been moved to github? If not we have a script to move trac tickets to github around here somewhere...

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2012-10-24**:
https://github.com/hershwg/github-migrate-trac-tickets